# play a video loaded from the database in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-json

I followed a tutorial that allows me to load data from a mysql database in a recycling android and everything is well done. Among the loaded data, there are links to videos and I would like that when the user clicks on a recyclerview element, that he can play the corresponding video. How can I do this please?

**here is the code that loads the videos from the database**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Adapter mAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncLogin().execute();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    RecycleClick.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            String url = data.get(position).sizeName;
            String name = data.get(position).fishName;
            String titre = data.get(position).catName;
            for(int i = 0;i<data.size();i++) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayVideo.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("title", titre);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Click\nPosition : "+(position+1)+"\nTitle : "+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RecycleClick.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemLongClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your json file resides
            // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
            url = new URL("http://192.168.43.196/vibe2/essai4.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Data DataItem = new Data();
                DataItem.fishImage= json_data.getString("ImagePath");
                DataItem.fishName= json_data.getString("AndroidNames");
                DataItem.catName= json_data.getString("titre");
                DataItem.sizeName= json_data.getString("url");
                DataItem.price= json_data.getInt("counter");
                data.add(DataItem);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            mAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

}
**and here is my click**

```
RecycleClick.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? How about opening a new activity with a videoview in it?

Comment: Yes I tried but precisely I do not know what to convey in the `intent.putExtra`

Comment: I would assume the `videoUrl` or a `videoId` which you can use to load all the information about the video?!

Comment: I think the same. look at my code and please tell me. I tried several combinations for hours already and still nothing.

Comment: I see your code. Did you try the the search and took a look at this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: yes i searched google a lot before arriving here. i know how to pass the data from one activity to another with `intent` but i would like to know what value should i transmit in the `intent.putExtra` given the data come from a remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.dismiss();
        final List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Data DataItem = new Data();
                DataItem.fishImage= json_data.getString("ImagePath");
                DataItem.fishName= json_data.getString("AndroidNames");
                DataItem.catName= json_data.getString("titre");
                DataItem.sizeName= json_data.getString("url");
                DataItem.price= json_data.getInt("counter");
                data.add(DataItem);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            mAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            RecycleClick.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new RecycleClick.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayVideo.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", data.get(position).sizeName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
                    finish();
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: you did not understand me. I want to play the video as soon as I click on an item in my recyclerview.

Comment: Are you getting the video url from your response?

Comment: I want to pass the url of the video that comes from the database in an intent to start the video in another activity

Comment: Try to print the url. Does you are getting it ?

Comment: I try but I have the error "can not resolve symbol data"

Comment: List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>(); declare this globally

Comment: the code copied well but I have this error when I click on an item in my recyclerview`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

Comment: Can u mention the line number ?

Comment: it's on this line: `String url = data.get(position).sizeName;`

Comment: Then, i have to look into the complete code in order to resolve the problem. Can you send that ?

Comment: I put update my question. let me know if you need anything else please

Comment: have you received?